# The best way to find the win percentage for a pandas DataFrame with win, loss columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns (`'win'` and `'loss'`) and I want to find the win percentage (`'win%'`) and pass it into the DataFrame. The thing is, for some rows, the entries are 0, so for those rows, I need to pass `np.nan` into `'win%'`.

The following code does the job:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[0,0],[2,1],[0,1]],columns=['win','loss'])
df['total'] = df['win'] + df['loss']
x=[]
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['total'].iloc[i] > 0:
        x.append(df['win'].iloc[i] / df['total'].iloc[i])
    else:
        x.append(np.nan)
df['win%'] = x
```

Therefore, the desired outcome is:

```
   win loss  win%
0   1   2    0.333333
1   0   0    NaN
2   2   1    0.666667
3   0   1    0.000000
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient (pandas-y) way to do it. Also, I don't want to add an unnecessary column (`'total'`) if I don't have to. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all the zero values to np.nan first (using replace), because:

```
np.nan / np.nan = np.nan
```

And:

```
np.nan + np.nan = np.nan
```

So:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,2],[0,0],[2,1]],columns=['win','loss']
).replace(0, np.nan)
df["win%"] = df["win"] / (df['win'] + df['loss'])
```

Comment: `df['win%'] = df['win']/df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: This doesn't distinguish between actual 0 and nan. Like, for 0 wins and 0 losses, it should be win%=nan but for 0 wins and 1 loss, win%=0.

Comment: Nevermind. `df.sum(axis=1).replace(0,np.nan)`.should do it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.